# How to find the most frequently occurring item in an array without mutating anything?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

I'd like to know how I can refactor this code in immutable implementation in pure javascript without using immutable.js.

```
var arr1=[3, 'oo', 'oo', 'oo', 2, 3, 'oo', 3, 'oo', 2, 4, 9, 3];
var mf = 1;
var m = 0;
var item;
for (var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
{
    for (var j=i; j<arr1.length; j++)
    {
            if (arr1[i] == arr1[j])
             m++;
            if (mf<m)
            {
              mf=m; 
              item = arr1[i];
            }
    }
    m=0;
}
console.log(item+" ( " +mf +" times ) ");
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Shotgun formatted single-character variables aren't very helpful in understanding this.

Comment: I just want to learn how to rewrite this in functional style programming and immutable implementation.

Comment: No, I mean *what is the code doing*. I get that you want to "make it more functional", whatever that means in this context. Nor is "making it more functional" a good terminal goal for code, but it's your code. But it appears that @certainperformance already figured out what you were doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to find the most frequently occuring item in the array. Count up the number of repetitions of each element with `reduce`, and find the maximum number of repetitions.

While reducing, make sure to return a *new* object for the accumulator each time so you don't mutate.

```js
const arr1 = [3, 'oo', 'oo', 'oo', 2, 3, 'oo', 3, 'oo', 2, 4, 9, 3];
const reps = arr1.reduce((accum, item) => {
  const newCount = (accum[item] || 0) + 1;
  return { ...accum, [item]: newCount };
}, {});
const maxTimes = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(reps));
const [recordItem] = Object.entries(reps).find(([, val]) => val === maxTimes);

console.log(recordItem + " ( " + maxTimes +" times ) ");
```

If you need to identify *all* items matching the record, then use `filter` instead of `find`:

```js
const arr1 = [3, 'oo', 'oo', 'oo', 2, 3, 'oo', 3, 'oo', 2, 4, 9, 3, 3];
const reps = arr1.reduce((accum, item) => {
  const newCount = (accum[item] || 0) + 1;
  return { ...accum, [item]: newCount };
}, {});
const maxTimes = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(reps));
const recordItems = Object.entries(reps)
  .filter(([, val]) => val === maxTimes)
  .map(([key, val]) => key);

console.log(recordItems.join(', ') + " ( " + maxTimes +" times ) ");
```

Comment: Thank you. I see arrow functions. I kind of know this code ❝ return { ...accum, [item]: newCount }; ❞ is returning an object. But where may I learn more about this style of coding? Thanks again.

Comment: Learn the array methods. You can *always* use array methods rather than `for` loops (which should arguably be avoided in most cases), and the array methods naturally lend themselves to a functional style of programming.

Comment: I see. I was also not aware of three-dot operator and am reading about it now. Thanks.

Comment: @zawhtut it's called the "spread syntax", and it's not an operator, as it's contextual and does not have a single return value.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can create a *very* functional approach:

```js
const array = [3, 'oo', 'oo', 'oo', 2, 3, 'oo', 3, 'oo', 2, 4, 9, 3]

const maxOccurences = array => Array.from(
  array.reduce(
    (map, value) => map.set(
      value,
      map.has(value)
        ? map.get(value) + 1
        : 1
    ),
    new Map()
  ).entries()
).reduce(
  (max, entry) => entry[1] > max[1] ? entry : max
).reduce(
  (item, count) => ({ item, count })
)

console.log(maxOccurences(array))
```

And not that I'd ever recommend doing this in production code, but you can modify the `Array.prototype` to extend this functionality as a member method of arrays for convenience:

```js
const array = [3, 'oo', 'oo', 'oo', 2, 3, 'oo', 3, 'oo', 2, 4, 9, 3]

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'max', {
  value () {
    return Array.from(
      this.reduce(
        (map, value) => map.set(
          value,
          map.has(value)
            ? map.get(value) + 1
            : 1
        ),
        new Map()
      ).entries()
    ).reduce(
      (max, entry) => entry[1] > max[1] ? entry : max
    ).reduce(
      (item, count) => ({ item, count })
    )
  },
  configurable: true,
  writable: true
})

console.log(array.max())
```

Comment: The code is very nice-looking, though `map.set` does mutate the `map` in question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes but it's just a temporary intermediate value that gets marked for GC as soon as it's passed to `Array.from()`. I'm not entirely sure why using `map.set()` is considered "bad" here, as the question is simply about trying a style of programming. From the context, it did not seem that immutability of _everything_ was a strict requirement for the implementation, though OP could choose to disagree with my interpretation of the question, in which case I'd be happy to delete my answer.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the user of the function cannot observe the mutation tho, so it doesn't matter. `map` is completely localized.